# Laravel 5, Password reset email not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel 5 application. I recently hosted it on shared server and tried  to reset the password. It is throwing the following exception.

**Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110]**

I am using default authentication driver.

The code in the Password controller is as follows:

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker  $passwords
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->passwords = $passwords;

        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can I see your mail config. located at config/mail.php

Comment: in config/mail.php set `'encryption' => 'tls'`,  or set `port' => 597,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting this error because the default value set in your .env file located in the root of your project has these values

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

change them according to your requirement and if these values are set correctly then change the values of config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

by

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
```

Comment: You mean you are not getting your emails delivered ? If so check if your php mail function working properly and if you are getting any error then update your question with that error. Also check your mail queue of mail server

Comment: Yes, emails are not delivered.. How can I check php mail function ?

Comment: Create a testfile.Php in your public folder and follow the instructions provided on http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp and see if you get an email. This will confirm whether mail function is working or not

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly. What do you think what might be wrong with password reset?

Comment: Please update your question with the solution so that people can get help with this later on.

Answer (score 1):

in config/mail.php set 'encryption' => 'tls', or set port' => 587,

"Also know that Mailtrap.io is a fake SMTP server for development teams to test, view and share emails sent from the development and staging environments without spamming real customers"