# Laravel on Namecheap shared hosting, Mailtrap not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110]**

As far as I can tell this is the exact same issue as this question here:[Laravel 5, Password reset email not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257394/laravel-5-password-reset-email-not-working)

I'm not using mail settings from `.env` (everything is commented out), so everything is configured in `config/mail.php`

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'no-reply@mydomain.com',
        'name' => 'mydomain.com',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', [username]),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', [password]),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

With these settings, I do not get the above error, but mail is not being delivered to the mailtrap mailbox. Locally, mail is working with the following `config/mail.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'noreply@mydomain.com',
        'name' => 'mydomain.com',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', [username]),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', [password]),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

I have tried with/without tls, ports 465 and 2525, and changing the mail driver from `smtp` to `mail`, but the first `config/mail.php` settings are the only ones I have found that do not produce an error.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: It seems you're not able to connect to the server. You should probably talk to the hosting service to find out why.

Comment: Silly me, this was exactly what was happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your gmail account to send emails, this might be happening because **google finds it suspicious**.

Try allowing your app from [here](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).

Log in to your gmail account and go the the security settings and let google know that it was *indeed* you who was trying to access your account.

> They put a block on sending emails like this because it looked
>   suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Pekka's comment was spot on. Just a matter of opening ports. Doh!